# Проблема загрузки изображений на сайте

Tags: html, вёрстка, сервер

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема? Я загрузил верстку на хостинг, ранее - на гитхаб, часть картинок не отобразилась. В консоле выдают ошибку: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()". Если правильно понимаю, браузер считает, что изображений нет или путь указан к ним неправильно, однако это не так - локально все работает, только при загрузке на сервер происходит такая дилемма. Заметил, что и на хостинге, и на гитхабе одни и те же картинки не загружаются. Может, кто-то сталкивался с подобной ошибкой?

Comment: Это не браузер так считает, а сервер, к которому вы обращаетесь за картинками. Посмотрите в запросах в девтулах браузера корректно ли формируются урлы картинок, отправляемые на сервер.

Comment: @AlexeyR. да, все пути прописаны верно. Я заново загрузил картинки на хостинг, ошибки поменялись на такие: "GET https://glottogonic-directi.000webhostapp.com/img/layer_55.jpg 404". Почему сервер считает, что файл не найден, когда он есть?

Comment: @Александр Их нету или какая-то проблема с картинками. Вот я по ссылке перешел, не загрузилось. Я думаю, что в путях проблема. Но тут сложно сказать не видя вообще никаких ссылок и тд

Comment: @Александр как Вы вообще получили этот адрес? Почему Вы считаете что там должна буть картинка?

Comment: @AlexeyR. это бесплатный хостинг, поэтому домен странный: glottogonic-directi.000webhostapp.com Картинка должна быть по этому адресу, поскольку соответствует пути в файловом менеджере. Может, я что-то путаю

Comment: Совсем не обязательно. путь после домена не обязательно соответствует пути в файловом менеджере. В том сервере, на базе которого ваше приложение работает должна быть возможность ассоциировать путь поле домена с путем на жестком диске.

Answer (score 0):

После загрузки верстки на любой из хостингов часть картинок не отображалась, потому что они были прописаны в неправильном регистре - в хтмл прописал в маленьком, а сами картинки были в большом, что не было критично для локальной верстки.
Проблему решил так: переименовал файлы.
Подробней об этой ошибке нашел [тут](http://htmlbook.ru/faq/pochemu-izobrazhenie-ne-pokazyvaetsya-na-sayte)